# Dashing dashboard linking widgets

Tags: javascript, ruby, coffeescript, dashboard, dashing

I am having a hard time linking widgets on my dashing dashboard. I read another post and got some help from dashing community, but, just am not able to link widgets

I have my text.coffee modified to have this section (sample is my other dashboard)

```
click: (event) ->
  location.href = "sample"
```

When I click on my text widget nothing happens. I also tried doing this, but nothing.

```
click: (event) ->
  location.href = "www.stackoverflow.com"
```

However, when I just add below line to onData section of my meter.coffee it redirects to stackoverflow.com.

```
location.href = "www.stackoverflow.com"
```

What am I doing wrong? Do you have an example that I can try out?

EDIT1:

I also tried the below suggestion without any luck.

```
click: (e) ->
  e.preventDefault()
  location.href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
```

Comment: What is the context from which this click triggered. Try add `return false` at the end. And `preventDefault` if there is a need in it should be at the end too, I guess.

Comment: I have the click event block in my meter widget like so, but, adding return false doesnt help.

class Dashing.Meter extends Dashing.Widget

  @accessor 'value', Dashing.AnimatedValue

  click: (event) ->
    location.href = "http://www.stackoverflow.com"
    return false

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Got help from the dashing community. Here is how it works. Just modify your dashboard erb to link the page you want to see

```
<li data-row="2" data-col="2" data-sizex="2" data-sizey="1" onclick="location.href='http://www.stackoverflow.com';">
  <div data-id="test_text_widget" data-view="Text" data-title="Test"</div>
</li>
```

Comment: Damn, I was about to write a version with onclick attribute=)

Comment: Thank you for your answer, you helped me out a lot! :)

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1**

The following will work when wanting to open the link in a new tab on click, and only want it on certain tiles on your dashboard:

```
onClick="javascript: window.open('http://url', '_blank');"
```

So for example in your `dashboard.erb` file you would have the following:

**Note:** *that in this example I have [Switcher](https://github.com/QubitProducts/dashing-contrib/wiki/Widget:-Switcher) setup (Need to have [dashing-contrib](https://github.com/QubitProducts/dashing-contrib) installed), and being used to switch between 2 tiles that are using different widgets ([Hotness](https://gist.github.com/yannrouillard/796fe74d4cbf0cf42f47), and the default List). This will work on any tile created. This is just where i happen to be using it.*

```
<% content_for :title do %>Dashboard Name<% end %>
  <div class="gridster">
     <ul>

       <li data-switcher-interval="5000" data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1" onClick="javascript: window.open('http://www.stackoverflow.com', '_blank');">
         <div data-id="data-id-name from .rb job" data-view="Hotness" data-title="Title of Widget" data-moreinfo="more information text" data-cool="1" data-warm="30"></div>
         <div data-id="data-id-name from .rb job" data-view="List" data-unordered="true" data-title="Title of Widget" data-moreinfo="more information text"></div>
         <i class="fa fa-warning icon-background-small"></i>                 
       </li>

     </ul>
  </div>
```

**Option 2**

Another way to do this is to add a function at the top of your `dashboard.erb`.

**Note:** This example will make all tiles clickable and open a blank tab if no url link is provided for the tile so its not an ideal solution but does work*

```
$(function bringToTop() {
  $('li').live('click', function(e){
    var widget = $(this).find('.widget');
    if(widget.data('url')){
    var url = widget.data('link');
    var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
    win.focus();
    }
  });
});
```

So your entire `dashboard.erb` file should look something like this:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
  $(function bringToTop() {
    $('li').live('click', function(e){
       var widget = $(this).find('.widget');
       if(widget.data('url')){
       var url = widget.data('link');
       var win = window.open(url, '_blank');
       win.focus();
       }
      });
     });
</script>
<% content_for :title do %>Dashboard Name<% end %>
  <div class="gridster">
   <ul>

    <li data-row="1" data-col="1" data-sizex="1" data-sizey="1">
       <div data-id="mydata" data-view="Hotness" data-title="Data Title" data-cool="20" data-warm="1000" data-link='http:\\www.stackoverflow.com'></div>
    </li>
 </ul>
```

**Note:**

Something That I have not tested yet but I have found while searching online is that using either of the above options I provided might not work on iOS devices. The issue, which might be fixed already, and i'm not knocking Gridster by any means, is with Gridster. There is an [Open issue for click events on iOS devices](https://github.com/ducksboard/gridster.js/issues/132) at over at Gridster.

Thanks to **Phylor** over at [GitHub](https://github.com/Shopify/dashing/issues/36) for providing a temporary fix/solution, which was confirmed working as of 2/21/2016 (not by me).

Just add the following to the top of your `dashboard.erb` file:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
   function openUrl(obj) {
   var widget = $(obj).find('.widget');
   var url = widget.data('url');
   window.open(url, '_blank');
   }

  $(function() {
   $('li').live('click', function(e){
      openUrl(this);
     });
   $('li').live('touchend', function(e){
      openUrl(this);
     });
   });
</script>
```

This is my first post so I apologize for any formatting errors, but figured it was time to start giving back to the community that has helped me out so much. Hope this helps!